# Time difference calculation

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm trying to track the total shipping time for something in hours.  I know what date and time, at the origin, it was sent and the UTC offset for that location.  I also know what the local date and time was at the destination when it arrived, and the UTC offset for that location.

Are there any libraries or tools in javascript to help out with this kind of thing, or do I need to roll my own?  What's the simplest approach?

Comment: I don't thing it is too much work for a library but time.js or moment.js might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend http://momentjs.com/ to any time traveler.